# Switch case request Boolean for 3 booleans

Tags: java, methods, switch-statement, boolean, case

returns true if (and only if) i is 1, 2, 3 or 4;
    'useSwitch' is invoked only with values i in the range from 1 to 5.

```
private static boolean useSwitch(int i) {
    switch(i * i + i) {
        case (-1 /* 1,2,3,4*/):
            return (false /* i !=5 */);
    }
    return (false /* TODO: modify this expression */);
}
```

what to put where TODO:modify this expression.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Clarify what you are trying to do!

Comment: Why not  `return (i>=1 && i<=4);` ? Is it an exercise ?

Answer (score 2):

Wont that work?

```
private static boolean useSwitch(int i) {
    if(i >= 1 && i >=4){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

or simply

```
private static boolean useSwitch(int i) {
    return (i>=1 && i<=4);
}
```

if you don't want to add anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you seem to want this will do the trick

```
private static boolean useSwitch(int i) {
    return i != 5;
}
```